# Github Actions checkout seem to not be able to authenticate my user

Tags: github, github-actions

So I'm quite new to Github actions and trying to implement an action in a workflow.
I need to clone/checkout repo_2 into where my workflow is located, repo_1. Both are private repos.
It looks like this

```
job:
    name: Cloning private repo
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Cloning
      uses: actions/checkout@v1
      with:
        repository: my-username/repo_2
        token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
```

I created a PAT and added it as a secret key to repo_2. However whenever I run the workflow I get the following error:

> [error]fatal: repository 'https://github.com/my-username/repo_2/' not
>   found

Seems to me like the authentication couldn't be verified. Is this what's happening? How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you try the version 2 of the `actions/checkout` so `actions/checkout@v2`.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Maybe you should open an issue on the github page of that action and report your experience with the two versions; this may be a bug.

Comment: btw the fix was switching to v2 as well as adding the secret key to repo_1 instead of repo_2